# Group data from database by category

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have below array with records from the sql query and I want to display record as per title element in the array.

In below array I have two records of fax 2 `title` then it should display one table header for `fax2` and display all rows related to fax `2title`.

Plz find the below screen for current showing result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ09H.png)

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => Fax 1 [workflow_id] => 152623 [company_name] => gord's test account inc. [opener] => Adam Guzzo [phone] => 514-572-2326 ) 

[1] => Array ( [title] => Fax 2 [workflow_id] => 152624 [company_name] => gord's test account inc. [opener] => Adam Guzzo [phone] => 514-572-2326 ) 

[2] => Array ( [title] => Fax 2 [workflow_id] => 953707 [company_name] => gord's test account inc. [opener] => Adam Guzzo [phone] => 514-572-2326 ) )
```

```
 <?php foreach($previousFaxes as $previousFaxesData) :  ?>

        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" class="tablesorter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left" colspan="8"><?php echo $previousFaxesData['title'];?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Workflow</td>
                    <td align="left">Phone</td>
                    <td align="left">Opener</td>
                </tr>  
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>   
<?php  endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I think table heading should same for all the data.

Comment: No. It should be different as per record in array

Comment: Plz find the attached img for current result

Comment: Then first try to make data in specifice pattern like `array('Fax 1' => array('First Row'), array('Second Row'), array('And so on'))`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below code, I tried to make it like you want and it would create the result as you expected in your screenshot, but there is a catch you have to make sure the array result only has the fields which you want.

Its a dynamic based on your array.

Output like: https://prnt.sc/nc1rrq

```
<?php
  $array = Array (
    Array  (
      "title" => "Fax 1,",
      "workflow_id" => "152623,",
      "company_name" => "gord's test account inc.",
      "opener" => "Adam Guzzo",
      "phone" => "514-572-2326",
    ),

    Array  (
      "title" => "Fax 2,",
      "workflow_id" => "152624,",
      "company_name" => "gord's test account inc.",
      "opener" => "Adam Guzzo",
      "phone" => "514-572-2326",
    ),

    Array  (
      "title" => "Fax 2,",
      "workflow_id" => "953707,",
      "company_name" => "gord's test account inc.",
      "opener" => "Adam Guzzo",
      "phone" => "514-572-2326",
    )
  );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1" cellpadding="2">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($array as $key => $value) {?>
      <tr bgcolor="#ccc">
        <td colspan="4"><?php echo $value['title']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <?php foreach ($value as $k => $val){?>
          <?php if ($k == "title") {continue; } ?>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder=""></td>
        <?php } ?>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <?php foreach ($value as $k => $val){?>
          <?php if ($k == "title") {continue; } ?>
          <td><?php echo ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $k)); ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><hr></td>
      </tr>

      <?php }?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not a good way. What if a record has 100 different titles? 100 loops?

Comment: Based on the question, I don't think there would be more records to show into form.